# JavaScript function to get Instagram ID

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, tampermonkey

I have a JavaScript function with an event button to get ID of instagram users, but the problem is that it will only get the ID of the first user, and if I try to go to another profile, it gives the ID of the old profile, instead of getting of the current page profile?

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Function to extract profile ID from the Instagram page
    function getProfileId() {
        // Extracting profile ID from the page source
        var pageSource = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
        var profileIdPattern = /"profilePage_(\d+)"/;
        var matches = pageSource.match(profileIdPattern);
        if (matches && matches.length > 1) {
            return matches[1];
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Function to copy text to clipboard
    function copyToClipboard(text) {
        GM_setClipboard(text, 'text');
    }

    // Function to create and append a copy button to the Instagram page
    function createCopyButton() {
        var button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = 'Copy Profile ID';
        button.style.position = 'fixed';
        button.style.top = '20px';
        button.style.right = '20px';
        button.style.zIndex = '9999';
        button.style.padding = '10px';
        button.style.border = 'none';
        button.style.backgroundColor = '#3897f0';
        button.style.color = '#fff';
        button.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        button.addEventListener('click', function() {
            var profileId = getProfileId();
            if (profileId) {
                copyToClipboard(profileId);
                console.log('Profile ID copied to clipboard:', profileId);
                alert('Profile ID copied to clipboard:\n' + profileId);
            } else {
                console.log('Profile ID not found.');
                alert('Profile ID not found.');
            }
        });
        document.body.appendChild(button);
    }

    // Run the function to create the copy button when the page is loaded
    window.addEventListener('load', createCopyButton);

})();
```

How do I fix it such, that it reloads everytime I go try get the ID of a new profile after the first one?

Comment: Going to another page likely doesn't actually _load_ a completely new page - but only loads content in the background, that then gets added to the current document, and elements that made of the content of previous pages, only get hidden. So the innerHTML would then contain _multiple_ occurrences of `"profilePage_XYZ"`, but your code matches only the first one of those ...

Comment: Is there a way to fix this then? It seems like to me that it should refresh the page everytime somehow, which is a lot of unnecessary loading to be made?

Comment: Try and match _all_, instead of just the first one - and then work with the _last_ match you are getting ...? (Not sure if IG only puts this into one single place of the document, or if there might be multiple occurrences of the _same_ user id.)

Comment: Have you tried using Instagram's API?